# Awaiting on AngularJs service $resolved property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, service

Simple problem with hopefully simple enough solution.

I have defined multiple services to perform CRUD operations with tags.

```
myApp.factory('GetTags', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/myApp/API/Service/GetTagList', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: { groupId: 'groupId' }, }, isArray: true,
    });
}]);

myApp.factory('GetTag', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/myApp/API/Service/GetTag', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: { tagId: 'tagId' }, }, isArray: true,
    });
}]);

myApp.factory('SaveTag', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/myApp/API/Service/CreateTag', {}, {
        query: { method: 'POST', params: {/*createObj*/}, }, isArray: true,
    });
}]);

myApp.factory('UpdateTag', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/myApp/API/Service/UpdateTag', {}, {
        query: { method: 'POST', params: {/*updateObj*/}, }, isArray: true,
    });
}]);
```

Later on in my controller I want to do something like this in my tags function:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'GetTags', 'GetTag', 'SaveTag', function ($scope, $routeParams, GetTags, GetTag, SaveTag) {
    ...
    // the goal of this function to keep a copy of
    // tags collection in client memory that mimics database
    // as well as adding selected tags to forms object
    // eg: myForm = {... Tags: [], ...}
    $scope.addtag = function (tag, subTag){
        ...
        if (!($scope.tags.length > 0)) {
            // skip checking and just add tag
            SaveTag.save({ Name: tag, Desc: "", ParentId: null, GroupId: 12, }, function (data) {
                console.log('save tag: ', data);
                //todo: should wait for data of save operation to comeback
                //      before moving on to requesting a full object
                GetTag.get({ tagId: data.Id, groupId: 12, }, function (data) {
                    console.log(' get tag: ', data);
                    tagObj = data.tag;
                });
            });
            // push newly created tag into tags collection
            $scope.tags.push(tagObj);
        ...
    };
    ...
});
```

I know a skipped a lot of details from my controller and function in question but basically the reason why I am calling `save` followed by `get` is because of the `tag + subTag` scenario. I didn't want to complicate the processing logic if I was to pass a complicated object to the server for processing. Say if I had to create a `tag` followed by a `subTag` the javascript logic would look like this:

```
...
// skip checking and just add tag and subTag
SaveTag.save({ Name: tag, Desc: "", ParentId: null, GroupId: 12, }, function (data) {
    //todo: should wait for data of save operation to comeback
    //      before moving on to requesting a full object
    GetTag.get({ tagId: data.Id, groupId: 12, }, function (data) {
        tagObj = data.tag;
    });
});
// push newly created tag into tags collection
$scope.tags.push(tagObj);

SaveTag.save({ Name: subTag, Desc: "", ParentId: tagObj.ParentId, GroupId: 12, }, function (data) {
    //todo: should wait for data of save operation to comeback
    //      before moving on to requesting a full object
    GetTag.get({ tagId: data.Id, groupId: 12, }, function (data) {
        tagObj = data.tag;
    });
});
// push newly created sub tag into tags collection
//todo: find parent index
$scope.tags[parent_index]["Elements"].push(tagObj);
...
```

But in case you wonder, yes, I could return full object from `save` operation which I probably will in the near future. It's better to reduce number of async calls because they impact overall performance.

But for now I have a few questions:

1. At the moment I have four different services declared as per Angular documentation. But it would be more efficient if it was a single factory with multiple functions. Can someone point me in the right direction here please.
2. Is it possible to somehow stop and wait for `data.$resolved` property to turn `true` when I call `save` service so that I can then call `get` services with returned value? Or perhaps there is an alternative method of doing this?
3. I am digging into `$q` of Angular Documentation to see if I can utilise something from here.

Just in case people wonder I have come across a few examples where people utilised `resolve` property with `$routeProvider`. Unfortunately my scenario is done in real time during user interactions.

Any help and all advice is greatly appreciated.

#### References:

1. AngularJs Docs - [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)
2. Very good explanation and examples - [Using and chaining promises in AngularJS](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-promises)
3. AngularJs Docs - [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) (last example shows use of `$promise`)

#### Update:

It seem that my hunch was right. While I haven't got it to work yet I feel the answer lies with `$q` and `chaining promises`. Now I just need to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question but I have found the solution that works.

#### Update:

OK, after digging about and scratching my head I came up with this code:

```
// skip checking and just add tag
SaveTag.save({ Name: tag, Desc: "", ParentId: null, GroupId: 12, }).$promise.then(function (data) {
    console.log('save tag: ', data);
    return data;
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log('data: ', data.Id);
    GetTag.get({ tagId: data.Id, groupId: 12, }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log(' get tag: ', data);
        return data;
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log('data: ', data.tag);
        $scope.tags.push(data.tag);
        tagObj = data.tag;
        //todo: check for duplicate records
        //      because repeater will complain and
        //      it's pointless to have duplicate tags
        //      on an item to begin with
        $scope.myForm.Tags.push(tagObj);
    });
});
```

Notice the `$promise` after each service call. `$promise` exposes the `raw $http promise` that is returned by `$resource`. This allows me to use `.then()` to chain additional logic.

So, in the end all I ended up doing is change the way I call my services. That is all.